# In HTTPS-callable Firebase Cloud Functions, is the name of the error code available in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm throwing this error from my cloud function (HTTPS-callable):

```
throw new functions.https.HttpsError('not-found', 'User account not found')
```

Then, on Android, I'm able to get the first parameter ('not-found') with

```
functions.getHttpsCallable("myFunc").call(data).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    if(e instanceof FirebaseFunctionsException) {
                        FirebaseFunctionsException ffe = (FirebaseFunctionsException) e;
                        FirebaseFunctionsException.Code code = ffe.getCode();
                        String errorName = code.name()
                })
```

errorName is that parameter.

But on iOS, there's no "name" for the error code.

```
functions.httpsCallable("myFunc").call(data) { (result, error) in
        if let error = error as NSError? {
            if error.domain == FunctionsErrorDomain {
                let code = FunctionsErrorCode(rawValue: error.code)
                let message = error.localizedDescription
                let details = error.userInfo[FunctionsErrorDetailsKey]
            }
        }
    }
```

All I get is an int code, and the second parameter ('User account not found'). Is the error name available somewhere? I was hoping to use that name to handle different errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the enums I was looking for:

Android:

```
@Override
public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
    FirebaseFunctionsException ffe = (FirebaseFunctionsException) e;
    FirebaseFunctionsException.Code code = ffe.getCode();
    if(code.equals(FirebaseFunctionsException.Code.ALREADY_EXISTS)) {
        // handle error
    }
}
```

iOS:

```
functions.httpsCallable("myFunc").call(data) { (result, error) in
    if let error = error as NSError? {
        if error.domain == FunctionsErrorDomain {
            let code = FunctionsErrorCode(rawValue: error.code)
            if code == FunctionsErrorCode.alreadyExists {
                // handle error
            }
        }
     }
 }
```